# Jquery/CSS Disable button click animation after an Jquery animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, button

My question is when i click the button it dose a `click` animation but when it´s open and then i click it it should stay and dont do the click animation. Is this even possible?.

Here The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6tZ4g/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>[**fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/q24ja/)</kbd>

```
var a_red = $(".a_demo_threee,.a_demo_threee_open"),
    content = $("#contentlogin");
content.hide(); //hides the content so its invisibil on the refresh/load of the website
a_red.click(function (e) { //opens the login
    e.stopPropagation();
    a_red.stop().animate({
        "width": "300px",
            "height": "200px",
    }, 1000);
    content.show();
    if (content.is(':visible')) {
        $(this).removeClass('a_demo_threee').addClass('a_demo_threee_open');
    }
});
$(document).click(function () {
    a_red.stop().animate({
        "width": "42px",
            "height": "39px",
    }, 1000);
    content.hide();
    a_red.removeClass('a_demo_threee_open').addClass('a_demo_threee');
});
```

---

change class to `a_demo_threee_open` when element with id `contentlogin` visible and switch back to `a_demo_threee` when it hide .

Comment: i found a bug when you click the opend tile it  will override the positions i tride removing the class '.tile' and added the class '.tile_open' but it still dose not work here is my try. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2Zx3m/15/)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class 'open' to $(".a_demo_threee") on click

```
$(".a_demo_threee").click(function (e) { //opens the login
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".a_demo_threee").stop().animate({

        "width": "300px",
        "height": "200px",
    }, 1000);

    $(this).addClass('open'); // <---- This is what I am adding

    $("#contentlogin").show();     
});
```

and then put this CSS:

```
.a_demo_threee.open {
     top: 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #9e8d84, 0px 5px 0px 0px darkred, 0px 10px 5px #999;
}
```

On clicking document, removeClass 'open'

```
$(document).click(function () {
   $(".a_demo_threee").removeClass('open').stop().animate({
        "width": "42px",
        "height": "39px",
   }, 1000);

   $("#contentlogin").hide();
});
```

JSFiddle -- http://jsfiddle.net/6tZ4g/1/